# How to make focus outline visible when it is obscured by graphic element?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on keyboard accessibility for my web design portfolio site. For each project I have a gallery of "devices" (phones, laptops, monitors) who's "screens" show pages from the various websites. The devices are SVGs that are layered on top of scrollable images. Looks great, works great, the only problem is that the SVGs block the focus outline when tabbing through the gallery.

Is there any way to make the focus outline always visible? Or change the z-height of a focus outline so that it is always on top? Or make it apply to the parent element?

The basic structure of the device object is:

```html
<figure class="device">
  <svg class="device__border" role="presentation" style="z-index:20">
  <div class="device__screen" style="overflow-y:scroll; z-index:10">
    <img class="device__screen-content" alt="Screen shot of website" src="...">
  </div>
</figure>
```

[Screen shot of portfolio site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOcqo.png)

The site is in development at http://cocohost.co/portfolio6/

I'm coding this site on a Mac. In Firefox, all the focus outlines are blocked by the SVGs. In Chrome, it's completely random. Sometimes they're hidden, sometimes they are not. I can tab forward and see and not see and outline, and then tab back to the same device and it will appear.

Answer (score 1):

The solution here was to apply a focus-within style to the figure element. For example:

```
figure:focus-within {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```